# Why wont Typescript let BehaviorSubject take a union type?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I believe this problem is purely Typescript related, and just happens to involve the BehaviorSubject in my case.

I know that both these lines:

```
    const myVariable: string | null = 'string';
```

and

```
    const myVariable: string | null = null;
```

are valid syntax. So along the same lines I have declared this BehavoirSubject:

```
    const user: BehaviorSubject<User | null> = new BehaviorSubject(
      null
    );
```

This doesn't work, as this error:

```
Type 'BehaviorSubject<null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<User | null>'.
  Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observer<null>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<User | null>[]'.
      Type 'Observer<null>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<User | null>'.
        Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
          Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
```

My expectation is that this BehaviorSubject should take either User or null types in this example, but it will seemingly only accept both at the same time as a single expected type, hence this works as a workaround:

```
const user: BehaviorSubject<User | null> = new BehaviorSubject(
    null as User | null
  );
```

The types themselves don't seem to matter, "string | null" and "User | string " both throw the same kind of error, so how should this kind of typing actually be done? I'd rather not have to typecast ever.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post a complete code example that is not working.  I was able to use a `User|null` type as a behaviorSubject without error in a playground.

Comment: Generally such assignments are compatible or not depending on the variance of the generic class

Comment: Try "new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null)"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By not specifying the type in the constructor, the generic type parameter is inferred to be `null`, not `User | null`. The type of the variable (`const user`) has no bearing on this (the assignment happens after the value construction and only performs a cast if any).

Explicitly specify the type of `T`:

```
const user = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
```

Comment: Dang, rookie mistake.
Good explanation, top lad :)
Thanks